# PHP - strpos didn't check first word

Tags: php

I'm trying to do some validation in PHP, and one of them is checking whether there is a specific word in the inputted string or not.
The problem is, my code seem to not working when I put the specified word first.

here's the code:

```
$word = "aa bb cc dd";
if(strpos($word, 'aa') == false)
{
    echo "wrong input";
}
```

but if I change the `$word` to either `bb aa cc dd` or `bb cc dd aa`, it works. I wonder how to fix this though.

Comment: See the warning in the PHP manual for that function. Hint: `===` (three): http://php.net/strpos

Comment: thanks for your help! i don't know the manual website before though so i'm getting `strpos` from another site(which the examples doesn't use any `===` . that's why i was confused with this :) thanks for all the answers though ! ^^ they really helps. wonder why i get minus just because asking this though >.> those minuses discourages me to ask questions whenever i'm confused >.>

Comment: Well if confused with a specific function, consult the manual and read first, at least I'd suggest you that. You can ask whatever you want, one day you might ask a great question and you get a lot of upvotes instead. Or you place some good answer.

Comment: since i got the link now, i think i'll check on it first instead of searching without knowing what i wanted to search for :) thanks for the suggestion though, will try to do that :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`strpos` will return false if your string isn't there. Otherwise, it returns the position of your string.

In this case, 'aa' is at the start of the string, which means that it's at position 0; and 0 evaluates to false.

You need to do a boolean compare on the result:

```
if(strpos($word, 'aa') === false)
```

Comment: Also note if you are using === true, then having your logic in the if statement, it doesn't work. You would better use === false, then have your logic in the else statement.

Answer (score 8):

That's because `strpos` returns the position of the word, in this case 0. 0 is falsey. `==` does not check for identical matches, `===` does. So use a triple equals.

It's even in [the docs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Comment: sorry, but i just know the docs site when you said it on this post :) but it works! thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

`strpos` is returning 0, as 'aa' is the 0th character. As `0 == false` but does NOT `===` false (it is not boolean), you need to use `===` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the strict comparison operator, this will match against the same type, so using `===` will check if it's a Boolean:

```
if(strpos($word, 'aa') === false)
{
    echo "wrong input";
}
```

Using `==` is a loose comparison, anything can be stated true (apart from `true`, `1`, `string`), e.g.

```
"false" == false    // true
"false" === false   // false
```

The reason why it's false because it's comparing a string against a Boolean which returns false.

Answer (score 3):

Because the position of `aa` is 0, which *equals* to `false`.

You have to use:
`if(strpos($word, 'aa') === false)`

Answer (score 1):

Add a space before search string and find more than 0 position

```
if(strpos(" ".$word, 'aa') > 0)
{
    echo "Found it!";
}
```